# What are the biggest changes between Diablo II & Diablo III?  

Tags: diablo-iii

The question says it all, what changed from Diablo II to III?

Comment: I swear that was a question like this, but I can't find =P

Comment: possible duplicate of [What new systems exist in Diablo 3?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27075/what-new-systems-exist-in-diablo-3)

Comment: I'm asking for changes, not new things.

Comment: Acctually, upon further evlauation I kind of agree with that one. He is asking for changes, not new systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://www.osirisguide.com/diablo-2-vs-diablo-3-a-running-list-of-differences/) site has the most comprehensive list.

**Here are the largest changes:**

1. Loot is now personal, meaning all of the gold and items that drop are exclusive to you. So nobody can come through and snatch up your loot.
2. You no longer place your skill points as you level. Stats are distributed based on your class and skills are unlocked as you go. You can constantly be changing your build to optimize situations and PvP.
3. Runes are now skill enhancers and can no longer be placed in weapon sockets to gain bonuses or create runewords.
4. There is a fourth difficulty called Inferno which is built to put your maxed out character to the ultimate test. It is very tough and has been said to be two times harder than the agreed difficulty the testers thought was sufficient.
5. Trading is now done through the auction house (much like WoW). There is an AH that you can use real money to purchase items and also a gold based AH. **NOTE:** You can sell items in the real money AH and gain real money without investing a dime into the system.
6. There are now Artisans, which are NPCs used to craft. You can salvage items much like you can in other RPGs and create gear. The gear created usually won't be better than what you can find naturally looting and slaying.

Those are the core changes, please refer to the site for a more comprehensive list. I will work on this a bit more when I get home but I have to get back to work. :)

Comment: That was fast!  Thanks a lot....I might just head over and grab myself a copy... What I like is the fact that they revamped the social aspects of it...